# SharePoint 2013 CSOM Update Editor

Tags: 2013, development, csom, file-upload, check-in

This issue seems to have come up time and time again, but unfortunately with no solution.

Basically I have a solution where I use CSOM to upload a document.

The code I have is like this

```
                p.ModifiedBy.ID = _sp.CurrentUser.Id;
                p.Modified = DateTime.Now;
                p.ModifiedByWinframe = u.getWinframe();

                lstItem.ProjectListItemFromEntity(p);
                lstItem.Update();
                spFile.CheckIn("Uploaded By xxxxxxxx", CheckinType.MinorCheckIn);
                _sp.ExecuteQuery();
```

There is more above but the basics are that I have a mapper (based on https://sennitspmapper.codeplex.com/) that takes the fields and then can map and unmap them to list items.

So in this example I'm trying to map the modified by fields to the list item and then update.

The modified by fields are '`Modified_x0020_By`' '`Editor`' and '`Modified`'
But whatever I do when I `CheckIn` it resets them to the AppPool user that the MVC application is running on.

I've tried things like this

```
var modifiedByField = new ListItemFormUpdateValue
                {
                    FieldName = CesaDocument.ModifiedByWinframe_Field,
                    FieldValue = u.getWinframe()
                };


                //try again to fix the author/Editor or CreatedBy/ModifiedBy CSOM 2013
                var updatedValues = new List<ListItemFormUpdateValue> { modifiedByField };
                lstItem.ValidateUpdateListItem(updatedValues, true);
                _sp.ExecuteQuery();
```

But 2013 doesn't seem to have ValidateUpdateListItem even though the docs say it does. Currently working on Micrsoft.SharePoint.Client 15.0.0

I had a bash at using the JavaScript REST Api through c# and http requests, but no dice.
Can't see anything glaringly obvious in the web services.

Is this even possible? In the past I've created a web service as a sharepoint solution and then use that to modify the fields.

Any other ideas?

UPDATE
Could a solution be to have a separate app pool running as ApplicationPoolIdentity and somehow have that upload the file?
Or change the appPool or is that just insanity!?

UPDATE
This is how I load the code, I'm using the mapper again to get the list item into a nice object.

```
this.Load(this.Web.Lists);
            List siteUserInfoList = this.Web.SiteUserInfoList;
            //this.Load(siteUserInfoList);

            var q = Camlex.Query().Where(x => (string)x["Name"] == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
            IEnumerable<ListItem> itemColl = this.LoadQuery(siteUserInfoList.GetItems(q.ToCamlQuery()));
            this.ExecuteQuery();
            this.CurrentUser = itemColl.FirstOrDefault().ProjectToEntity<CesaUser>();
```

Comment: Can you confirm the code `_sp.CurrentUser` in MVC gives the current logged in user in SharePoint? Or it returns the app pool account?

Comment: Hi there the _sp object is an extension of the ClientContext object. The _sp.CurrentUser is basically from the SiteUserInfoList - I'll post in the code

Comment: @AhmadZia - notify

Comment: Can you update created and created by columns. I dont think the solution you are after is possible. Sorry I haven't found any solution but may be someone else updates that post.

Comment: @AhmadZia You can update the created and created by columns that seems possible. It's just the modifed person gets overwritten when you do the checkIn. I did have a way around using Sandbox solution, but SP2013 seems to have sealed that hole. In the end it's looking like a powershell job. On a slight plus, they seems to have solved this on SP365 but we are building an inhouse application and SP365 isn't possible.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, sometimes you look at these things for so long that you loose the focus and you think you might have missed something.